# Referring Kusto Materialized views while it is being created

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am running a microservice that triggers the async creation of Materialized views to the Kusto engine, and in the same process, it creates some User Defined Functions which refer to the above-created materialized views. But the Kusto engine is failing the function creation queries with 400.
I don't see any other issue causing bad query errors, so I want to confirm if we can refer to materialized views while they are being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a function that references an entity that doesn't exist yet (e.g. a materialized view that is still in the process of creation), you can use [the `skipvalidation` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-function#supported-properties) when creating the function.

**Note**: if there are other issues with the logic in your function, they will *not* be validated either.

An alternative way would be for your process to periodically poll for the materialized view creation operation's status, using [`.show operations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/operations#show-operations), wait for it to complete successfully, and only then create the function referencing it (without having to use the aforementioned flag)

Comment: What happens if I try to run the user-defined function which refers to these materialized views? Will they return any result based on what data has materialized until now, or will it throw some error?

Comment: When a query references an entity that doesn't exist yet, it will fail with a semantic error.